# issues with php if statement

Tags: php, mysql

ok so i am pretty new to php. i am making a site listing different attractions, i have a details page where i display information for each attraction stored in a mysql database. i'm trying to write an if statement so an icon will show if the relevant attraction has for example disabled facilities and so on. I have a tables attractions, type, facilities and faciliteslink in the database.

In the facilitieslink i have the columns: 
AttractionID
FacilityID

in the Facility table i have:
FacilityID
FalilityName

in the attractions table i have: 
AttractionID
name
summary ect...

also here is the if statement and queries i was trying to make

```
$myQuery  = "SELECT Attraction.*, Type.TypeName ";
$myQuery .= "FROM Attraction ";
$myQuery .= "INNER JOIN Type ON Attraction.Type = Type.TypeID ";
$myQuery .= "WHERE AttractionID=" .$_GET['ID'];

//run query
$result = $con->query($myQuery);
if (!$result) die('Query error: ' . mysqli_error($result));
?>
<?php
    $myQuery .= "INNER JOIN Type ON Attraction.AttractionID = facilitieslink.FacilityID    ";
 ?>

<?php
            //display attractions row by row
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {

    echo '<div class=" sixteen columns" id="attraction-details">';
    echo    '<h3><a href="attractions.php">Attractions/<a href="details.php?ID=' . $row['AttractionID'] . '">' . $row['Name'] . '</a></a></h3>';
    echo    ' <div class="eight columns" id="big-a-image1">';
    echo        ' <img src="'. $row['ImageUrl'] . '"/>';
    echo    ' </div>';
    echo    ' <div class="eight columns" id="big-a-image2">';
    echo        ' <img src="'. $row['ImageUrl2'] . '"/>';
    echo    ' </div>';
    echo    ' <div class="eight columns" id="big-a-image3">';
    echo        ' <img src="'. $row['ImageUrl3'] . '"/>';
    echo    ' </div>';
    echo    ' <div class="eight columns" id="big-a-image4">';
    echo        ' <img src="'. $row['ImageUrl4'] . '"/>';
    echo    ' </div>';
    echo'               <div class="two columns" id="m-thumb1">';
    echo'                   <a href="#"><img src="'. $row['ImageUrl'] . '"/></a>';
    echo'               </div>';
    echo'               <div class="two columns" id="m-thumb2">';
    echo'                   <a href="#"><img src="'. $row['ImageUrl2'] . '"/></a>';
    echo'               </div>';
    echo'               <div class="two columns" id="m-thumb3">';
    echo'                   <a href="#"><img src="'. $row['ImageUrl3'] . '"/></a>';
    echo'               </div>';
    echo'               <div class="two columns" id="m-thumb4">';
    echo'                   <a href="#"><img src="'. $row['ImageUrl4'] . '"/></a>';
    echo'               </div>';
    echo        ' <div class="eight columns" id="a-description">';
    echo'           <h4> Attraction Description </h4>';
    echo            ' <p class="para"> ' . $row['Description'] . ' </p></a>';
    echo        ' </div>';
    echo'               <div class="two columns" id="thumb1">';
    echo'                   <a href="#"><img src="'. $row['ImageUrl'] . '"/></a>';
    echo'               </div>';
    echo'               <div class="two columns" id="thumb2">';
    echo'                   <a href="#"><img src="'. $row['ImageUrl2'] . '"/></a>';
    echo'               </div>';
    echo'               <div class="two columns" id="thumb3">';
    echo'                   <a href="#"><img src="'. $row['ImageUrl3'] . '"/></a>';
    echo'               </div>';
    echo'               <div class="two columns" id="thumb4">';
    echo'                   <a href="#"><img src="'. $row['ImageUrl4'] . '"/></a>';
    echo'               </div>';

// everything else works apart from this    
        $id = $row["AttractionID"];
            if ($row['FacilityID'] == 1){
    echo'   <img src="'. $row['icon'] . '"/>';
            }
            else



    echo'</div>';

    echo'       <div class="eight columns" id="directions">';
    echo'               <h3>Directions</h3>';
    echo'               <p class="para"> ' . $row['Address'] . ' </p>';
    echo'       </div>';
    echo'       <div class="eight columns" id="video">';
    echo'               <h3>Video</h3>';
    echo'                ' . $row['VideoEmbed'] . ' ';
    echo'       </div>';


    echo'               <div class="eight columns" id="contact">';
    echo'                   <h3 id="con"> Contact </h3>';
    echo'                   <p class="para"> ' . $row['Long'] . ' </p>';
    echo'               </div>';                    
    echo'   <div class="eight columns" id="opening-times">';
    echo'       <h3 id="open"> Opening times </h3>';
    echo        ' <p class="para"> ' . $row['OpeningHours'] . ' </p>';
    echo'   </div>';
}


    ?>
```

Comment: Where's the rest of the query? Your first command has `.=`, implying there was a statement initializing `$myQuery`. Besides, the query can't start with `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: What `$result` has to do with `$myQuery`?

Comment: P.S. you are missing a `';` at the end of the `echo` statement, which will cause errors.

Comment: You're missing the command to actually execute the query.  At some point you before you use `$result`, you need to initialize it with `$result = $mysqli->query($myQuery)`

Comment: Okay, now that you posted the code for running the query, you can't modify the query after calling `query()`.  Also, without seeing your schema I can't be sure, but I think you meant to have `facilitiesLink` instead of `Type` in your second `INNER JOIN`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your main question:

> "would i store the icon in this table or 1 of the others?"

- Which table is "this table"? You already mentioned 3 Tables now  (Attraction, Facility and Type)
- What shall this Icon show? The answer to this question can tell you, where the data belongs to:  Types or attraction. Can every attraction have another icon? or does the Type tell you, which icon you have to choose?

You try to join the Type by `FacilityID` and another time by `TypeID`. Are both unique in your table Type? Otherwise you're going to get multiple rows for the same Attraction. Due to your Edit i now know you want to join a third table: Facility. You have to write `INNER JOIN facilitylink ON Attraction.FacilityId = facilitylink.FacilityID INNER JOIN Facility ON facilityLink.FacilityId = Facility.FacilityId` to solve your problem with a join. But beware that you may get above mentioned multiple rows of attraction. Furthermore, due to the properties of an inner join, you will loose information on attraction which don't have a facility. Maybe you should switch the first `INNER JOIN` into a `LEFT JOIN`, what will produce NULL assignments to unknown Facilities. Don't forget to add the Information you additionally need (Icon, FacilityId) to the SELECT-Part. I suggest you to search further information on **how to write select-statements** and what effect which Statement parts will have.

The **Syntax of your SQL-Statement** is messed up because you append (PHP-Operator `.=`) a Join-Part after the Where-part. You don't execute the manipulated query, is the Manipulation needed in this case? Change the position of appending the Join-Part before the Query-Command and adjust the Order to get a correct SELECT-Statement.

You're appending a **user generated input without proper escaping** to the query (`.$_GET['ID']`). This is a very common beginners failure. Please Take a look into the topic "SQL Injection" and prevent this by using "prepared statements"

Your **Appending** the content of `$row['icon']` **directly into the generated HTML**. Is the Content given by the users or do you generate/declare it? In the first case you should escape it with `htmlspecialchars($row['icon'])`

you're not starting the php file properly. I think you cut of some code, but just in case: all php Code need to be behind a `<?php`. the `?>`will command the interpreter to stop interpreting php-code at all. A new `<?php` will start the interpreter again.

```
<p> HTML-Code here
<?php
  echo "PHP-Code here";
  echo "more PHP-Code here";
  echo "much more PHP-Code here";
?> </p><p>some more html code </p><?php echo "and some PHP-Code again";
  echo "but this time until the Ent of the File!";
```

This also means, that you have some redundant code in your example:

```
?>
<?php
```

Hopefully i have directed you in the right direction.

**EDIT**: Edited some of the Sentences above due to your Edit.

Comment: some of the code at the start was missing. anyways thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if this query is good because i'm not sure about it.

The code whould go like this... Assuming the table is "attraction"

```
// Define query
$query = "SELECT * FROM  `facilitieslinks` WHERE  `AttractionID` = '".$_GET['ID']."'";

// Create connection
             $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","&&&&&YOURUSERNAME&&&&&","&&&&&YOURPASSWORD&&&&&","&&&&&YOURDATABASE&&&&&");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

//Execute the query to the DB
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

//Process data
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $id = $row['AttractionID'];
    if ($row['FacilityID']==1) 
    {
    echo "<img src=\"".$row['icon'].\"">";
    }
}

// Close the connection 
mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: the query is wrong i tried to display info from the facility table... echo' <p> ' . $row['FacilityName'] . '<p>'; and it wouldn't work.

Comment: can you post the structure of your table.  Meaning all the fields in order. It's almost done ;)

Comment: attraction: Name, Summary, Description, OpeningHours, type, Area, ImageUrl, facilitieslinks: AttractionID, FacilityID  facility: FacilityID, FacilityName, icon

Comment: updated my answer.  it should work. let me know what happens.

Comment: ye. sorry it wouldn't work. i don't have much time before i need to hand it in so i moved on to something else. thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: FacilityID in J:\xampp\htdocs\site\details.php on line 202

Comment: changed the database name as it seems to be facilitieslinks, not attraction. Let me know what it rendered